# architectural questions on bigcouch cluster set up in two data centers

Tags: couchdb

What would be an ideal setup for these requirements: -- can read and write data from both data center -- if either data center is lost, the other can take over

The options I can think of : -- say if we have 6 servers, put 3 in one data center, the other 3 at the other center, set up the six servers as one cluster, is latency (nodes exchanging info, internal replication within the cluster) an issue?

--set up one cluster at each data center and have them replicate to each other. But how to set up master master replication though, do you have to do on individual node level?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

BigCouch 0.4 introduces a "zones" feature that might meet your requirements:

> ... the killer addition to BigCouch 0.4 is support for ‘zones,’ which
>   allows you control over where you place the individual copies of your
>   data. Cloudant’s hosted service makes extensive use of this feature to
>   protect against isolated failures in individual data centers. As an
>   example, our west coast cluster “Meritage” is actually spread over two
>   different data centers in two distinct geographic regions. We use
>   zone-support to ensure that at least one copy of all of our customers’
>   data exists in both locations. That way, if one location falls into
>   the ocean or is subject to nuclear attack, our customers’ data is
>   still safe and available. With this feature now in BigCouch, you can
>   extend clusters across multiple locations.  -- http://blog.cloudant.com/bigcouch-zero-point-four/